# New to Json -- Parsing JSON file using Vb.net and Newtonsoft

Tags: json, vb.net

I'm new to json  and trying to extract image/jpeg values for each subject ID from the following json data stream. I'm not sure how to traverse the various ID's and get the jpeg file locations.
I think the jobject.SelectToken("subjects.locations") should work but don't know how to format the request to get the values. IF that isn't appropriate any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

```
{
   "subjects":[
      {
         "id":"89729965",
         "metadata":{
            "roll":"1",
            "site":"C06"
         },
         "locations":[
            {
               "image/jpeg":"https://njstargazer.org/subject_location/9962fe64-f6ab-4c93-b0d4-8ef04f4414ec.jpeg"
            },
            {
               "image/jpeg":"https://njstargazer.org/subject_location/1a4f908b-8dd1-4d0c-aa58-d8563bdcdaba.jpeg"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":"89729964",
         "metadata":{
            "roll":"2",
            "site":"C06"
         },
         "locations":[
            {
               "image/jpeg":"https://njstargazer.org/subject_location/9962fe64-f6ab-4c93-b0d4-8ef04f4414ec.jpeg"
            },
            {
               "image/jpeg":"https://njstargazer.org/subject_location/1a4f908b-8dd1-4d0c-aa58-d8563bdcdaba.jpeg"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Probably something like: `dim imageLinks = JObject.Parse([JSON]).SelectToken("subjects").Children().SelectMany(function(subj) subj("locations"))`, if you don't want to deserialize to classes -- I've fixed your JSON, it wasn't valid. You should make sure that you post something that can be used as is, for others to test it

Comment: Thanks Jimi. I just cut  a piece from the file which was very lengthy. I'll give you recommendations a shot. Thanks again for the reply.